# Isolated Points

Tags: analysis

Show an open set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ contains no isolated points.

My attempt:
well if we can show an arbitrary element $a \in A$ is a limit point then we will be done. So since $A$ is open, there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(a) = (a - \varepsilon, a + \varepsilon) \subseteq A$. To show $a$ is a limit point, we need to construct a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ with $a_n \neq a$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and such that $(a_n) \rightarrow a$. I'm confused on how to construct such a sequence. Or is it easier to prove this statement by contradiction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $a_n = a + \epsilon/(2n)$ . This is a sequence in the set that converges to $a.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: About every point must exist a neighborhood of radius greater than 0 that is a subset of A. Take an arbitrary point ,x, and neighborhood, B, of radius h, such that B $\subset$ A. Let N$\epsilon \gt$ h, where N $\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\epsilon \gt 0$.  You can find a point of B for n $\ge$ N in each smaller neighborhood of x of radius $h\over{n}$.